# Having trouble formatting value as a percentage using print

Tags: python, pandas, printing, format, yfinance

I have this code:

```
from empyrical import max_drawdown
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr

myStartDate = "2017-01-01"
myEndDate = "2017-04-30"
myTicker = "SPY"
myData = pdr.get_data_yahoo(myTicker, myStartDate, myEndDate)
daily_close = myData[['Adj Close']]
returns = daily_close.pct_change()
mdd = max_drawdown(returns)
print("My max drawdown:", mdd)
```

The Output is:

```
My max drawdown: 0   -0.026101
dtype: float64
```

I want the output to be displayed as a percentage with 2 decimal places. For example:

```
My max drawdown: -2.61%
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Try `mdd.iloc[0]`

Comment: This gets rid of the "0" so that I just have -0.026101 and then using print(f"My max drawdown: {round(myVal*100, 2)}%") worked

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
myVal = mdd.iloc[0]
print(f"My max drawdown: {round(myVal*100, 2)}%")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform the variable into a regular float, for example:

```
print(f"My max drawdown: {round(float(mdd) * 100, 2)}%")
```

or alternatively:

```
print("My max drawdown: {0:.2f}%".format(float(mdd) * 100))
```